# How to automatically hide all slug fields in ModelForm based forms in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a model with `SlugField`. Value of that field is created when the model instance is saved for the first time:

```
from django.db import models
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify as default_slugify

class SlugModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk:
            self.slug = self.slugify(self.name)
        return super(SlugModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def slugify(self, tag):
        slug = default_slugify(tag)
        return slug
```

If i use that model in `ModelForm` the slug field is by default displayed.

```
from django.forms import ModelForm

class SlugModelForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SlugModel
```

How to automatically prevent all `ModelForms` from displaying of all of it's `SlugFields` without manually specifying `ModelForm.exclude` or `SlugField(editable=False)` on each form/field?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could also extend Lychas response, create a base class and inherit from that one:

```
class MyModelForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
    exclude = ('slug',)
    abstract = True

class AnyForm(MyModelForm):
#more here
```

This is untested though.

Answer (score 2):

You can [exclude fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/forms/modelforms/#using-a-subset-of-fields-on-the-form) in the Meta class by assigning field names to `exclude`:

```
class Meta:
    model = SlugModel
    exclude = ('slug',)
```